# Within the context of NGRX selectors how to create a selector that will return a set of objects where you have given a list of id(s) for those objects

Tags: typescript, rxjs, ngrx

The way ngrx goes about returning a set from a passed array out of the stored state, seems wrong.  I'm using ngrx-entities so, as you all know an entity is actually stored as an associative array with some sort of key and an object.

I have written selectors that look like this:

```
export const selectSanctuariesState = createFeatureSelector<fromSanctuary.SanctuariesState>('sanctuaries');

export const selectSanctuaryById = (id: string) => createSelector(
    selectSanctuariesState,
    sanctuaryState => sanctuaryState.entities[id]
);
```

This makes good sense to me, that it will find the exact entity that I am looking for.  The problem occurs when I expand the idea to select multiple entities.  To me is seems like it will work (I know it will work) but it will do it wrong:

```
export const selectAllSanctuaries = createSelector(
    selectSanctuariesState,
    fromSanctuary.selectAll
);

export const selectSanctuariesById = (ids: string[]) => createSelector(
    selectAllSanctuaries,
    sanctuaries => sanctuaries.filter(sanctuary => ids.some(ii => sanctuary.id === ii))
);
```

Notice, I should be able to just use the set of ids as keys, like I am above through the key to each of the object(s) within the hash or dictionary.  However this code seems to first put all the objects into an array and then filter through that array of the objects within the array that have the id that I'm looking for.  this just seem like i'm slowing the whole process down.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You might consider passing a list of id's as selector props, and within the filter predicate simply check whether item's id is in the id array passed via props.

Comment: kalexi, yes, that would be great, how do you build that selector?

Comment: Check this out: https://blog.angularindepth.com/ngrx-parameterized-selector-e3f610529f8
Long story short, instead of receiving `(sanctuaries) => sanctuaries.filter(...)`, you receive `(sanctuaries, props) => sanctuaries.filter(sanctuary => props.ids.some(ii => sanctuary.id === ii))` instead. You then subscribe like this: `this.store.pipe(select(selectSanctuariesById, { ids: ["1", "2", "3"] }));
`

Comment: kalexi, Still seems like your just going against the array (filtering) instead like in the above when I am using the key directly on the entity

Comment: Yep, but we're reusing the selector now. Regarding your actual question, do I understand you correctly that you don't want to `filter`, and instead wish to retrieve by key? If so, you can remake `sanctuaries` to be a `Map<string, your_sanctuary_type>`, and retrieve by key. But before you do it, I say do a benchmark and measure, whether it'll really be faster. The answer depends on how large the `sanctuaries` array is going to get, and how many keys you're  fetching from it. If `sanctuaries` is less than 100 elements large, I say don't bother. It might very well get slower.

Comment: kalexi, will do... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're working with a large collection (what is large?) you won't notice it.
What comes to my mind if you would want to do key lookups is to use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
export const selectSanctuariesById = (ids: string[]) => createSelector(
    selectAllSanctuaries,
    sanctuaries => ids.reduce((arr, id) => arr.concat(sanctuaries[id]), []))
);
```

Comment: timdeschryver, This looks right.  So, in your code, sanctuaries are the entities hash and your picking them with the sanctuaries[id], statement, I'll give it a try...